# .bind() not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have following simple javascript code which i wrote to scroll the terms and conditions textarea and after scroll reaches at the end of the terms and conditions textarea it should enabled accept checkbox , its working in chrome but not in ff and ie please help .

javascript code:

```
    $('#blogger_agreement').bind('scroll', function()
   { alert('hiii');
     if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight)
       { 
          $('#TermsOfService').removeAttr('disabled');
       }
    });
```

html :

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label"><br/>

</label>
<div class="controls">
<textarea name="blogger_agreement"  id="blogger_agreement" class="deadline_date"  rows="15" cols="15" style="resize: none;background-color:white; overflow-y: scroll; height: 350px;" disabled >
<?php 
$file_handle = fopen(FOLDER_PATH_HTTP."terms_and_conditions.html", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) 
{
   echo fgetss($file_handle);
}
fclose($file_handle);
 ?>
</textarea>
</div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">
        <input id="TermsOfService" type="checkbox" name="TermsOfService"  required="required" disabled="true" />

    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div style="width:90%;float:left;margin-top:5px;">I Accept the Terms and Conditions of The Motherhood.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use $(this).eq(0) instead of $(this)[0]

Comment: @c-link applied not working it can't alert 'hiii' in ff and ie

Comment: Try `$('#blogger_agreement').bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
        $('#TermsOfService').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});`

Comment: @arun : applied not working , please see my updated quetion

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery 1.7 `on` is the preferred method of attaching event handlers:

```
$('#blogger_agreement').on('scroll', function()
```

Even so, it should work. See this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtHt5/)** which works in Chrome 33 and Firefox 28 - alert is called.

Then see **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtHt5/1/)** which is similar to yours, but changes text. Both work in Chrome and Firefox (at least they do for me).

What version of jQuery, Chrome and Firefox are you using?

Comment: sorry for asking question wrong please see my updated question

Comment: @sameerpatil - is the problem that the checkbox is not enabled or that the alert does not show?

Comment: problem is : alert does not show  , it wont go further.

Comment: I tried .on,.trigger,.delegate,.live  ...... but nothing seems to work  please help ... (sorry for spelling mistakes if any ...)

Comment: @sameerpatil - does my second fiddle work for you in Firefox - do you see the change to accepted? If it does then it must be something different about your setup. Try using console.log() instead of alert() incase the alert is causing a break. Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the browser to see if the event handler is called?

Comment: I have tried your second fiddle it works on chrome but not on ff and ie , i also use console.log() but it appears that the event handlers .on or .bind are not getting called .....

Comment: @sameerpatil - interesting. It works fine for me. What version of FF are you using?

Comment: @sameerpatil - I have to step out, but will check back later.

Comment: thanks for all of your answers...... i got the reason why .bind, .on or any other jquery event was not called in ff and ie .... the reason was that the text-area i was scrolling was made disabled hence those events wont work ....... thanks again...

Comment: @sameerpatil - glad you got it.